# Seeking explanation about the usage of index() method in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

What is the usage of this particular section of this line of code :

```
[number_sets.index(number_set)]
```

According to my understanding, index() is an inbuilt function in Python, which searches for a given element from the start of the list and returns the lowest index where the element appears.

However, this does not apply to the usage of index() in this case.

```
# Create original list
number_sets = [[2, 4, 6], [3, 6, 9], [4, 8, 12]]

# Create empty list to copy into
square_sets = []

# Start outer for loop to iterate over inner lists
for number_set in number_sets:

    # Add a new empty list to the new list for each iteration
    square_sets.append([])
    
    # Start inner for loop to iterate over numbers and append them into the new list
    for number in number_set:
        print("The original number is %d, and the result is %d." % (number, number ** 2))
        square_sets[number_sets.index(number_set)].append(number ** 2)

print(square_sets)
```

Comment: It's just using the index of the number set in the original number sets list to insert into the same index in the square sets list.

Comment: Why do you think your definition does not apply in this example?

Comment: ```[number_sets.index(number_set)]``` it looks for the index of ```number_set```  in ```number_sets```

Comment: @Chris Thanks for ur help :) i get it now !

Comment: @Aru thanks for ur help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index is a Method of list, so the statement `[number_sets.index(number_set)]`
works like this:

`[name_of_your_list.index(element)` and by definition:

Returns the index of the first element with the specified value.
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_list.asp

Maybe running your code through:
http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display
could help you to better understand what is happening.